# Does anyone still keep the F# Powerpack v 1.9.9.9

Tags: f#-powerpack

I am managing to install YOGI (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/yogi/), however this software need the exact version of F# Powerpack (1.9.9.9) and I cannot find that library because the link http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/40168 is unavailable. If anyone still hold the copy of that library please contact me, my email is trucnguyenlam@gmail.com

P/S: Newer version of this library does not work. It must be followed the instruction http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/yogi/readme.txt